# How to authenticate user to Firestore Go SDK?

Tags: firebase, authentication, go, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the [Firestore Go SDK](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore) from a client application. This looks like a client-side SDK, based on the functions, but that might be my first error?

I'm struggling to authenticate the user to Firestore. I've already logged them in using the [REST API for Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password). This returns me an ID token, refresh token, etc. How do I use this with the Firestore SDK?

The docs suggest I need to call [`firestore.NewClient(<context>, <project-id>, <option>)`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#NewClient). For the latter argument, I've tried [`option.WithCredentialsJSON(...)`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/option#WithCredentialsJSON) passing a JWT-decoded ID token. I've also tried passing the raw refresh token. In both cases, the SDK complains about what I'm passing.

How can I authenticate the user based on the tokens I've obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go SDK for Firestore is meant to be used in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. It doesn't have a way to sign the user of the application in, but instead authenticates itself with the server with administrative credentials, which you'll don't want to have on non-trusted devices.

Comment: Can you explain how this decision "_The Go SDK for Firestore is meant to be used in a trusted environment_"  is beneficial to anybody or how it accomplishes the _trusted environment_ requirement in the context of the OP? One can use the Firestore Go SDK in a trusted or untrusted environment, but by using the Go SDK _not_ authorize users with an ID Token. However by using Firestore REST API on that same trusted or untrusted environment you can authorize users by setting the ID token in the `Authorization` header of the request.

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDKs don't work like client SDKs -- as an example, they bypass security rules for Firestore and Cloud Storage, and offer non-client activities like listing and deleting users in Firebase Auth. Firebase does not offer a client SDK for Go, and the Admin SDK is not well-suited to an untrusted client environment.

Answer (score 0):

`option.WithCredentialsJSON` accepts not JWT token, but Google Application Default Credentials.

Other option is to provide path to the file with Google Application Default Credentials using environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` since firebase sdk is a part of the `cloud.google.com/go` sdk.

Check out the examples (also with other options).

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-go

https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go#example-package--ApplicationDefaultCredentials